# Need help in radiobutton within gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, radio-button

Thru radio button i am selecting the data from gridview. Here all radio buttons are selectable at a time. Actually it should not happen at a time user can select only one button which i could not do. My second problem is when i am selecting particular radiobutton that details should be displayed in text box. I have Itemid, ItemName, Quantity, Rate and Total field in gridview. These values i have inserted thru textbox so i have all the corresponding text box for all. So once i select particular radiobutton those details should be displayed in corresponding textbox. I have done the insertion coding for this but couldn't do selecting thru radiobutton and dispalying in textbox. Pls somebody help me in coding for this problem.

Thanks,
sumit

Answer (score 2):

Sumit,
Don't use the html control, use the asp control:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioSelector" runat="server" GroupName="RadioSelectors" />
```

I had a similar problem in an ASP.NET class, and I followed [this](http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/tutorial-51-cs.aspx) tutorial which worked perfectly.

Comment: +1 for the tutorial, which does solve the radio button problem from the question.  However, I'm not certain what you mean in the first part of your answer.  Your advise to use the html radio button control is not valid (according to the tutorial) and your example code is of an ASP control, not an HTML control.

Comment: thanks, Jason.  I flipped the wording by mistake. I've edited my comment to reflect what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the classic master/detail pattern see here:

[Tutorial 10: Master/Detail Using a Selectable Master GridView with a Details DetailView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx)

You are fighting the intended workings of ASP.NET databound controls by using radio buttons. I don't like having select links either they're not exactly Web 2.0! but they can be quite easily replaced with a row click by doing this (or variation of same):

[Select a row in an asp:GridView without using a Select Command](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/view9FC28EE6-ACB0-4F51-BFE4-38B0B10134D5.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I read several articles on the net but none were suitable.  I finally figured out my own solution without using either HTMLControls radiobutton nor using Javascript.  This works for my requirement.

---

**My Gridview html settings were as follows**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="grdVersion" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
        AutoGenerateEditButton="false" PageSize="10" Width="400px" 
        EmptyDataText="No records available."
        OnRowDataBound="grdVersion_RowDataBound"
        AutoGenerateSelectButton="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="versionid" HeaderText="Version No." ItemStyle-Width="50px"
                ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HtmlEncode="true" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="version_date" HeaderText="Version Date" ItemStyle-Width="100px"
                ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HtmlEncode="true" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="remarks" HeaderText="Remarks" ItemStyle-Width="150px"
                ItemStyle-Wrap="true" HtmlEncode="true" ReadOnly="true" />

            **<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Admin" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdCurrent" runat="server" 
                    Checked="false" Enabled="true" GroupName="rgVersion" 
                    AutoPostBack="true" 
                    OnCheckedChanged="rdCurrent_CheckChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>**

             </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

---

**The server code (C#) was as follows,**

```
   DataTable dtDataSpaceVersions; //place this inside the codebehind page class
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            dtDataSpaceVersions = ListDataSpaceVersions();
            ViewState["dtDataSpaceVersions"] = dtDataSpaceVersions;

            PopulateGridVersion();
        }
    }

    protected void PopulateGridVersion()
    {
        grdVersion.DataSource = dtDataSpaceVersions;
        grdVersion.DataBind();
    }



    protected void rdCurrent_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Control selectedVersion = ((Control)sender).Parent;

        if (ViewState["dtDataSpaceVersions"] != null)
            dtDataSpaceVersions = (DataTable)ViewState["dtDataSpaceVersions"];

        foreach (DataRow dtr in dtDataSpaceVersions.Rows)
        {
            if (dtr["versionid"].ToString() == ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow)selectedVersion.Parent).Cells[0].Text)
                dtr[3] = "Y";
            else
                dtr[3] = "N";
        }
        PopulateGridVersion();
    }


    protected void grdVersion_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        DataRowView drv;
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.DataItem != null)
        {
            drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            if ((RadioButton)(e.Row.FindControl("rdCurrent")) != null)
                if (drv.Row.ItemArray[3].ToString() == YesNo.N.ToString())
                    ((RadioButton)(e.Row.FindControl("rdCurrent"))).Checked = false;
                else
                    ((RadioButton)(e.Row.FindControl("rdCurrent"))).Checked = true;

            //setGridUserPermissionCheckBoxState(e.Row, drv);
        }
    }


   public DataTable ListDataSpaceVersions()
    {
        string sql = string.Empty;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("versionid", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("version_date", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("remarks", typeof(String));
        dt.Columns.Add("is_current", typeof(String));

        DataRow dtr;
        dtr = dt.NewRow();
        dtr[0] = "1.1";
        dtr[1] = "12-Dec-2005";
        dtr[2] = "Campaign Information";
        dtr[3] = "N";
        dt.Rows.Add(dtr);

        dtr = dt.NewRow();
        dtr[0] = "1.2";
        dtr[1] = "06-Mar-2006";
        dtr[2] = "Sales corrections";
        dtr[3] = "N";
        dt.Rows.Add(dtr);

        dtr = dt.NewRow();
        dtr[0] = "1.3";
        dtr[1] = "24-Aug-2009";
        dtr[2] = "Invoice reconciliation";
        dtr[3] = "Y";
        dt.Rows.Add(dtr);

        dtr = dt.NewRow();
        dtr[0] = "1.4";
        dtr[1] = "30-May-2010";
        dtr[2] = "Invoices verification";
        dtr[3] = "N";
        //dtr[0][0] = "";

        dt.Rows.Add(dtr);
        return dt;
    }
```